# "Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /myService

Tags: spring, http, soap, http-status-code-404, soapui

I'm trying to hit a service. I am able to see the response in the http log. I see success message in the soapUI Log. But in the soap response i see the http 404 error.

In the http log.. at the end.. it is showing

```
Thu Jul 30 15:00:01 IST 2015:DEBUG:<< "Connection: Close[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 30 15:00:01 IST 2015:DEBUG:<< "Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 09:30:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 30 15:00:01 IST 2015:DEBUG:<< "Server: WebSphere Application Server/8.0[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 30 15:00:01 IST 2015:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
Thu Jul 30 15:00:01 IST 2015:DEBUG:<< "Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /myService
```

I'm trying to use this service response. I need this response, to run my code.

Please help in showing up the response on the Soap response  column instead of http log.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that application myService is not deployed on the application server. What is the name of application? myService or MyService?